# Xpath Selectors - is it possible to find elements by title in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I've been trying to build a bot that scrapes the name of followers liking a picture in instagram. The website opens a popup box with the accounts in side, and the box seemingly refreshes the account links as you scroll it. I've written a code that will open the box and then scroll it, but i can't get selenium to scrape the account names. My code looks like this to scroll the pop up box:

```
realscroll_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div')
while last_ht != ht:
last_ht = ht
time.sleep(2)
ht = browser.execute_script('''
                            arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);
                            return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
                            ''', realscroll_box)
namelinkstemp1 = realscroll_box.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href,"/")')
```

But it gives me this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[starrts-with(@href,"/") because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[starrts-with(@href,"/")' is not a valid XPath expression.

The text i'm trying to extract looks like this:

```
<a title="instagramusername" href="/instagramusername/">
<div class="                   Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm                                                                                                              ">
<div class="_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm KV-D4            fDxYl      rWtOq">
<div class="                   Igw0E   rBNOH        eGOV_     ybXk5    _4EzTm                                                                                                              ">instagramusername</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Any help is appreciated, xpath queries are very new to me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Was your xpath really `starrts-with`? You misspelled the function name. It has too many `r`'s.

Comment: I hope not! Seems my code was full of errors from start to finish. That's embarassing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starts-with function finds the element based on attribute value. In your code function is not correct . Also `//*[contains(@href,"/")` , here you missed `]`
Correct one : `//a[contains(@href, '/')]`

```
  //*[starts-with(@href,'/')]
```

or

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'/instagramuse')]
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Silly mistake on my part to miss the bracket. When you say Starts-with finds using an atrribute value, what do you mean?
Thank you again for helping!!

Comment: so it will identify elements from the DOM whos attribute value ( in your case ::href) starts with /